# as.exe - entry point not found the procedure entry point __printf__ could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: windows, mingw

Yt works early.when I try to use gcc commend it show me. I already uninstalled and re-installed gcc 4.8.

this is error:

```
as.exe - entry point not found
the procedure entry point __printf__ could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\as.exe"
```

this is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'd rather post this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.)

The error seems to be related to the start of `as`, not to your code. You can check by running `as --help` (it should display a long list of options). Assuming this command also fails, continue with reading.

The whole error looks a bit weird, but I guess your issue is caused by multiple conflicting DLLs in your `PATH`. You should be able to test this hypothesis by going into `c:\mingw\bin`, clearing `PATH` completely (`set PATH=` in the Windows shell; `export PATH=` in Bash) and trying to execute `as --help` again. If that helped, you need to identify what program in your `PATH` is causing this and either remove it from `PATH` completely, or remember to set a custom, short, non-conflicting `PATH` everytime you want to use your mingw installation.

Comment: .I know it beacuse the file path had space. like /Source [space] C/test.c.

Comment: and I already solve this and if  you use windows 10 the without space isnt the without space it changed.Means some program install path must without white space and sopport in 10.

Answer (score 13):

I know it's too late to answer, but maybe it can help someone else.

I have just faced this problem, it is solved that change the directory name (in MinGW directory)  from mingw32 to mingw32old. Because these two directory has as.exe in their bin directory, so they conflicts, and occures error. However, now it is working,

hope benefits to your problems.

Comment: You can use `where as` to find which conflicting paths are pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `as.exe` can also be sourced from `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\` which might conflict with `c:\MinGW\bin\`. I suggest to experiment as @DavidMacek did - remove `c:\MinGW\bin` from `PATH` and reboot the shell and then type `as --help` to see if things are fine.
 If things are fine. Goto your environmental variable and "move up" `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\` above `c:\MinGW\bin\` to let `msys` take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a path to the as.exe to the system environment variables and it worked.
In my case it was path to the Code blocks gcc compiler on Windows 10: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin